# Класс String. Перегрузка операторов

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

Помогите найти ошибку в коде.

Задание глобальное:"Создать класс String".

На одном из этапов надо добавить в класс метод int String::length(), который возвращает длину строки и перегрузить для класса
операцию [] так, чтобы можно было обращаться и менять элементы строки: char& operator[] (int).
С помощью указанных методов поменять местами первый и последний символы в строке.

Пример:

На входе: "Lorem Ipsum has been"

На выходе: "norem Ipsum has beeL"

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String{
    int len;
    char *str;
public:
    String (): len(0), str(nullptr){}
    String(const String&src);
    String(const char *str);
    ~String();
    int length(String &);
    char& operator [](int index){
        return str[index];
    }
    friend istream &operator >>(istream &in, String &s);
    friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, String s);
};
String::String(const String &src){
    len = src.len;
    this->str = new char[len+1];
    strncpy(str, src.str, len);
    this->str[len] = '\0';
}
String::String(const char*str){
    len = strlen(str);
    this->str = new char*[len+1];
    strncpy(this->str, str, len);
    this->str[len] = '\0';
}

String::~String(){
    delete [] str;
}


int String::length(String &s){
    len = strlen(s.str);
    return len;
}

istream &operator >>(istream &in, String &s){
    char *buf = new char[100001];
    in.getlin(buf, 100000);
    s.len = strlen(buf);
    s.str = new char[s.len];
    for(int i = 0; i < s.len; ++i)
        s.str[i] = buf[i];
    delete [] buf;
    return in;
}
ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, String s){
    for(int i = 0; i < s.len; ++i)
        out << s.str[i];
    return out;
}

int main(){
    String s;
    cin >> s;
    char tmp = s[s.length];
    s[s.length] = s[0];
    s[0] = tmp;
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Исправил this->str = new char*[len]; на this->str = new char*[len+1];

Comment: Для чего хранится одновременно `len` и нуль-терминатор в буфере? В разных случаях используется то одно (len), то другое (строковые функции, которые опираются на нуль-терминаторы).

Comment: `s[s.length] = s[0];` не скомпилируется (в классе нет ни поля с таким именем, ни перегрузки квадратных скобок) и в рантайме будут проблемы, ибо в конструкторах явно в эту позицию (подразумеваемая `len`) вставлятеся нуль-терминатор.

Comment: Отсутствует деструктор - память не освобождается.

Comment: По поводу len и буфер не понял вопроса. Почему неправильно s[s.length] = s[0] ? Деструктор  сейчас добавлю.

Comment: `String::length` зачем-то принимает `String&`, а потом считает `len`, который и так уже известен.

Comment: `&operator <<` принимает строку по значению, т.е. каждый раз копирует (напоминаю, тут у нас утекает память, когда удаляется локальный объект-аргумент)

Comment: Отвечаю: потому что по этому адресу в конструкторе происходит `this->str[len] = '\0';`, это значение такой операцией затёрлось бы первым символом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кое-что несколько подзапущено...

Вот, смотрите. Я бы еще добавил запрет выхода за границу массива в операторе `[]`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class String
{
    size_t len;
    char *str;
public:
    String (): len(0), str(nullptr){}
    String(const String&src);
    String(const char *str);
    ~String() { delete[] str; }
    size_t length() const { return len; };
    char& operator [](size_t index)
    {
        return str[index];
    }
    char operator [](size_t index) const
    {
        return str[index];
    }
    friend istream &operator >>(istream &in, String &s);
    friend ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const String& s);
};

String::String(const String &src)
{
    len = src.len;
    this->str = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(str, src.str);
}

String::String(const char*s)
{
    len = strlen(s);
    str = new char[len+1];
    strcpy(str, s);
}

istream &operator >>(istream &in, String &s)
{
    char *buf = new char[100001];
    in.getline(buf, 100000);
    delete[] s.str;
    s.len = strlen(buf);
    s.str = new char[s.len+1];
    strcpy(s.str,buf);
    delete [] buf;
    return in;
}
ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const String& s)
{
    return out << s.str;
}

int main()
{
    String s;
    cin >> s;
    char tmp = s[s.length()-1];
    s[s.length()-1] = s[0];
    s[0] = tmp;
    cout << s;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Harry - добавляя проверку выхода за границы в оператор [], вы нарушаете соглашение стандарта C++ о том, что [] не проверяют границы (их проверяет at()) - и таким образом, учите молодого человека писать плохо поддерживаемые программы.

Comment: @gbg Учебный класс вы называете стандартом? :) И еще - покажите это место в стандарте, что оператор `[]` не должен проверять выход за границы. Не в `vector` или там `string`, а в самопальных вещах. А потом идите спорить со  Страуструпом, который даже в вектор этот функционал засовывает в своих *Программировании...* или *A Tour of C++* :)

Comment: Ваш хамский тон и посылание во все стороны плохо сочетаются с ублюдошными смайлами. 
Стандартная библиотека ведет себя очень просто [] - не проверяют диапазон, at() - проверяет. Если джуны начнут совать в свои реализации [] проверку на диапазон (вместо того, чтобы назавать это at()) - путаницы будет только больше.

Comment: @gbg,  причем тут стандарт и какую путаницу может создасть проверка(проверка, это не обьязательно  генерация иключения)? И кто мешает кому то написать свой собственный string для удобства выполнения проекта, совершенно не похожего на стандартный?...

Comment: @gbg Ну, если *по существу* вам нечего сказать, на этом и остановимся. Пар выпустили? :)

Comment: По существу: когда программный код становится интеллектуальной собственностью и обретает определенную жизнь, его нужно сопровождать. В процессе этого сопровождения, его будут читать и модифицировать. И чем больше нестандарта будет в написанном  - тем дороже сопровождение. Например, просто так заменить велосипедный контейнер на стандартный уже не получится - стандартный выход за границы проверять не будет. Конечно, при обучении преподы на это плевать хотели, приходится джунов переучивать, после светочей то.